# How can I format a decimal value from a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, format, decimal

I have the following code:

```
string myDecimalString = "9000000,10";
decimal myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(myDecimalString);

Console.WriteLine(myDecimal.ToString());
```

The code below writes `9000000,10` as output but I want `9.000.000,10` for the output. The value in `myDecimalString` can be different so I need a generic solution for that...

Hope that you can help me.

Best regards
Timgo

```
string myDecimalString = "9000000,10";
decimal myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(myDecimalString);

Console.WriteLine(myDecimal.ToString("N1"));
```

That was as close as I can get but in this case I get `9.000.000,1` and not `9.000.000,10`

Comment: What Culture do you want to use that uses that formatting?

Comment: Where did you get the N1 format? Did you read all the info about the N specifier? Hint N2

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=net-8.0#system-decimal-parse(system-string-system-iformatprovider)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{myDecimal:0,000.0}");`

Answer (score 0):

```
private string Format(string inp){
    string a = "90000000,10";
    var f = a.Split(',');
    var d = f[0].Reverse().ToArray();
    string res=d[0].ToString();
    for (int i = 1; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i%3==0)
        {
        res += '.';
    }
    res += d[i];
}
return res.Reverse().Aggregate("", (s, c) => s += c)+','+f[1];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you need specific format with group separators you can always create custom number format info to your liking:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
nfi.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3 };

Console.WriteLine(9000000.10m.ToString("N2", nfi)); // 9.000.000,10
```

If you know what culture has desired decimal separator, group separator and group sizes you can use that culture information directly similar to:

```
// 90,00,000.10
Console.WriteLine(9000000.10m.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("en-IN")));
```